# How to read polyline lat/long from directions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline, map-directions

I am trying to convert my v2 Google Maps code to v3 and I'm having problems getting the polyline from directions.  Basically I am trying to get the lat/long all along the path at specific interval (every 100 miles or so).  In the past I used getPolyline and getVertexCount.  I would then divide the VertexCount by number of miles and get an approximate number in the polyline that I should be looking at.  I know with v3 both of those commands are gone.  I've used the below code to get the polyline but I'm unsure that I'm getting anything because when I run an alert I get [object Object].

```
var map;
var gdir;
var poly;
var tempstr;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {     

    var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
    };
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.0, -107.0)

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline;


    setDirections("Colorado Springs", "Phoenix");

    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());

    var thispathlatlong;
    thispathlatlong = poly.getPath();
    alert(thispathlatlong);

    });

} 


function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress) {


    tempstr = {
        origin:fromAddress,
        destination:toAddress,
        provideRouteAlternatives: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL

    };

    directionsService.route(tempstr, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
    });

}
```

It draws the directions but I can't get the lat long from the array.  I know it's now in a MVCarray but I don't know how to use that.  I can't read it.

This is my site http://www.orbitalspeeds.com/

To be specific, I am trying to get the directions polyline that Google creates when plotting a route.  Most of the help I've found is about making a polyline; I want to grab the one that Google Maps creates and parse the lat/longs into an javascript array that I can use later.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Custom Directions Renderer, creates a polyline (and custom markers) from the DirectionsService response](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html), [Example that pulls the geographic data from the DirectionsService response and formats it as XML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggable2Xml.html)

Comment: I think I found my answer here:
http://marx-tseng.appspot.com/maps/Polyline_from_directions.html